# Swift : affect struct by reference or "alias" to a variable

Tags: swift, struct, reference

I have to update a struct, but this struct needs a long expression to be found from my viewController :

```
let theMessage:Message? = self.messageSections.first(where: { $0.date == DateDMY(fromNSDate:msg.date) })?
        .msgs.first(where: { $0 == msg })
```

I want to mutate one property of this struct, but not a copy of it, I want to update it "where it is", that is in messageSections[].msgs[]

The problem here is that if I try this code after the one above :

```
theMessage.status = .NOT_SENT
```

Only the local copy will be updated, and not the real one in messageSections[].msgs[]. So when I reload my collectionView, nothing changes.

I could do

```
self.messageSections.first(where: { $0.date == DateDMY(fromNSDate:msg.date) })?
        .msgs.first(where: { $0 == msg }).status = .NOT_SENT
```

But if I have to manipulate this property several times in my function, I dont want to re-write the whole expression each time. So what I'm looking for is something like in C :

```
let theMessage:Message?* = &self.messageSections.first(where: { $0.date == DateDMY(fromNSDate:msg.date) })?
    .msgs.first(where: { $0 == msg })
if(theMessage != NULL) 
    theMessage->status = .NOT_SENT
```

I saw in other questions that I could use & before argument and inout before parameter name, but its only for functions calling. I'm looking for a way to create an alias for a big expression when affecting a variable, just to avoid re-writting it each time.

Comment: Gotta get the indices instead of the elements. `firstIndex`.

Comment: @Kevin lol good approach I didn’t even think about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `firstIndex` to get the index of the element in the array, then access the element directly using the retrieved index.

```
if let messageSectionIndex = self.messageSections.first(where: { $0.date == DateDMY(fromNSDate:msg.date) }), let messageIndex = self.messageSections[messageSectionIndex].msgs.firstIndex(where: { $0 == msg }) {
    self.messageSections[messageSectionIndex].msgs[messageIndex].status = .NOT_SENT
}
```

Comment: Thanks I ll do that:)